# How to prevent a value from being multiplied due to user inputs?

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a fitness tracking website. Users can add weight loss goals and use a calorie calculator to calculate how many calories they've lost from certain exercises. I've implemented a progress bar which shows the users calorie loss progress. It also shows two values, one for the total number of calories the user has lost, and a value for the target number of calories the user is aiming to lose.

When I add more than one goal, the target number of calories value is correct, however, the value showing how many calories the user has lost seems to get multiplied by how many goals have been entered by that user.

I'm struggling on how to prevent this from happening and for the value to show how many calories the user has lost regardless of how many goals have been set.

For example, a user has burned 1310 calories in total. When a second weight loss goal is added by the user, this calorie loss value doubles to 2620 without the user inputting any weight loss activities.

This is the query I've used...

```
$sql = "SELECT 
      SUM(calories) as calories
      , CASE g.weightunit
          WHEN 'lbs' THEN 3500
          ELSE 7700
        END * weightlost  as target_calories 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM goal ORDER BY weightlost DESC) g 
        INNER JOIN tracklog t USING (userid)
    WHERE userid = ? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['userid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($calories, $target);
$res = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: This is normal with the type of query you are using. Why do you have a weight unit on the table and what do you use it for? What if it changes on the different goals?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The weight unit is needed as the users goals are displayed on their account dashboards so they can keep track of what they set. They can only choose from lbs or kgs.

Comment: It seems unclear what variables go with what  data. (i.e. to have weightlost as target_calories... so is that counting the total calories from weight lost or is that counting the targeted amount of calories needed to be burned?)  Anyway, I think your multiplication must be because you are retrieving multiple rows and always summing the calories burned (times by the amount of goals).  I'd suggest looping through each goal for a user and add units that way instead of grabbing them from one query.

Comment: @Vbudo It's targeting the amount of calories needed to be burned. Ok thanks, I'll give that a go!

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining the unit level, *goal*, to aggregate level, *tracklog*, then join by `userid`. Right now, you join both at unit level then aggregate, summing multiple times for multiple matches along joins.

```sql
SELECT t.SumCalories, 
       CASE WHEN g.weightunit = 'lbs' THEN 3500 ELSE 7700 END *
           g.weightlost As Target_calories 
FROM goal g
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sub.userid, SUM(sub.calories) as SumCalories      
   FROM tracklog sub
   GROUP BY sub.userid) t 
USING (userid)
WHERE g.userid = ?
ORDER BY g.weightlost DESC
```

*By the way, likely you are using MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_ON` setting to `off` as the engine does not through a syntax error for having no specified non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY` clause.*

*Every other RDBMS would thrown an error for this. As best practice, always use `GROUP BY` to specify groupings in aggregate queries to avoid unreliable results.*